# prepared Statements nodejs postgresql returns error no parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, server, psql

i have been informed that my queries could be at risk to SQL injection, so I have attempted to change them. However, now whenever I do get requests I get an error stating there is no parameter $1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
app.get('/users', async(req, res) => {
     try {
        const {id} = req.params;
        console.log(id)
        const user = await Query(`SELECT * FROM client where id = $1`, id)
        console.log("error ",user)
        res.json(user[0])
     } catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
     }
 });
```

error: there is no parameter $1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `console.log(id)` print `undefined`? It looks like you are getting the id from the path parameters of the URL, however your path doesn't seem to have any parameters. Try adding `:id` to your path

i.e.

```js
app.get('/users/:id', async(req, res) => {
     try {
        const {id} = req.params;
        console.log(id)
        const user = await Query(`SELECT * FROM client where id = $1`, id)
        console.log("error ",user)
        res.json(user[0])
     } catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
     }
 });
```

And then call it like GET `/users/1` for example to get user with ID 1.

Comment: @SenamAhadzi No problem! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.